# I want to kill exe from Task Manager

Tags: vb.net

i have one exe,when this exe is called ,some this is exe is already open in task manager,i want kill all previous exe not current exe,i am using VB.net

Comment: You've got to at least have made an effort for us to make an effort, too.  Have you got some code you've already written?  Please post us what you have.

Comment: Do you really want to programmatically terminate earlier instances of your program?

Comment: Well, usually, when a previous instance of the same application is found running, one choose to kill the current instance and switch to the previous instance. At least you don't risk to loose data.

Answer (score 1):

As previous commenters have noted, you really should make more of an effort to solve the problem yourself (and demonstrate you've tried already)

Saying that, here are a few hints:

```
taskkill.exe /F /IM myprocess.exe /FI "PID ne 555"
```

[Process.GetProcessesByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx)

[Process.GetCurrentProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess.aspx)

[Process.Kill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx)

Be very careful killing processes.  As Anton Kovalenko noted already, are you *really* sure you want to do it?  It may be better to simply warn of the condition and provide instruction to the user/admin.

Answer (score 0):

Set your program up to receive messaging.  When the most current instance launches have it send a message to the previous instance to itself shutdown gracefully - and of course put the code in place to do this.